# Android getting CardView must be terminated by the matching end-tag error

Tags: android, android-cardview

when I try to use `CardView` I get this below error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug'.
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Volumes/Home/Projects/Android/cafeAlachiq/app/build/res/layout/channels_item_fields.xml; lineNumber: 92; columnNumber: 7; The element type "android.support.v7.widget.CardView" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>".
```

I search and check CardView open and close tag but I don't find problem and android studio rendering correctly layout

this is my layout structure, please help me to resolve this problem. clear project and rebuild that couldn't resolve this problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/category_lists_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.pishguy.androidapplication.cafemaku.Libraries.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/category_avatar"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                app:civ_border_color="#000"
                app:civ_border_width="4dp"
                app:civ_shadow="false"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/category_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/category_description"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/count_channels"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is this channels_item_fields.xml which you have posted?

Comment: @Raghavendra yes,

Comment: In the error log its saying error at lineNumber: 92 but the above xml doesn't have that many lines :)

Comment: Did u try by clean and Rebuild?

Comment: @Raghavendra closing and reopening android studio cause of resolve problem